# unable to update cart items quantity in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

i have been stuck in vuex store , i dont know how to update the cart item quantity, add to product working fine but how we would change the quantity cart items
can any one let me know,

**action.js**

```
export const updateCart = ({ commit, dispatch }, { product, quantity }) => {
commit('UPDATE_CART', { product, quantity });
```

Cart.update({
product_id: product.id,
quantity
});

}

**mutation.js**

```
export const UPDATE_CART = (state, { product, quantity }) => {

let productInCart = state.cart.find(item => {
  
    return item.product.id === product.id;
});

if (productInCart) {
    productInCart.quantity += quantity;
    return;
}



state.cart.push({
    product,
    quantity
})
```

}

**cart.vue**

```
<input class="quantity-spinner" type="text" @keyup="updateCart(item,$event)" :value="item.quantity" name="quantity">
methods: {
goToRoute(name){
        this.$router.push(this.$baseUrl+'/'+name)
    },

...mapActions("cart", [
  "removeProductFromCart",
  "clearCartItems",
  "getCartItems",
  "updateCart"
]),

updateCart(product,e)
{
    this.quantity = e.target.value;

    this.updateCart({
        product:product,
        quantity: parseInt(this.quantity)
    });
}
```

},

Answer (score 0):

To update the store, you need to dispatch the action.

**cart.vue**

```
updateCart(product, e)
{
    this.quantity = parseInt(e.target.value);
    this.$store.dispatch('UPDATE_CART',{ product, quantity: this.quantity })
}
```